# Ionic content Section overlap with one anither

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have two ionic content section, these two sections overlap with one another. Here I'm listing down my code ..

**section 1**

```
<ion-content>   
 <p>Hi this is App</p>
</ion-content>
```

**section 2**

```
<ion-content>   
 <p>Hi this is Ionic</p>
</ion-content>
```

These two sections overlap with one another. I'm not able to figured out what might be the reason. could any one please let me know solution how to avoid this overlapping

Comment: Both are on same component?

Comment: yeah both are in same component

Comment: these two files are having in `home.html`

Answer (score 1):

As per the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#content) -

> There should only be one content in a single view component.

So you should wrap your content into single `ion-content` tag like this -

```
<ion-content>   
 <p>Hi this is App</p>
 <p>Hi this is Ionic</p>
</ion-content>
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dnbntg?file=app%2Fapp.html)

Comment: have you Checked my example?

Comment: yeah , I  copy past the code which is mentioned in example. But still same error